# How to open Flutter app from Instagram via link

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking

I have a Flutter app and I want to open it from links on Instagram
I know that I should use Deep-link but as Instagram uses in app browser it seems more steps is needed.
can anybody help me with this?